# how to auto share in facebook once form is submitted

Tags: php, facebook, forms, facebook-graph-api

I have a php form for facebook for a certain media house.To fill the form, the media house facebook profile should be liked first. When the profile is liked then only the form is accessible. I have so far succeeded in that. Now when the form is successfully submitted I want to share some info as `XXX applied for "YYYY" campaign` automatically in the fb profile of XXX. Is it possible? I have done facebook sharing with asking permission only. Is it possible to share some info after successfully form submission without asking for permission.

Any help / suggestions are welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: _“I want to share some info as XXX applied for "YYYY" campaign automatically in the fb profile of XXX”_ – that is a __violation__ of [Platform Policies](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/): _Everything_ that you post in the name of the user has to be a 100% _created_ by the user himself. Please don’t create another _spam_ app of this kind (it’ll most likely get you blocked quite soon anyway, because FB is not to stupid to figure out that “magically” all of your users post exactly the same text).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In success page I added the following code:
Before

```
<?php
require_once('php-sdk/facebook.php');
$config = array(
    'appId' => 'XXX',
    'secret' => 'YYY',
    'allowSignedRequest' => false,
);
$facebook = new Facebook($config);
$user_id = $facebook->getUser();
Facebook::$CURL_OPTS[CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST] = 2;
$message = 'Message Here;
?>
```

Then in body part:

```
<?php
if($user_id){
 try(){
  $ret_obj = $facebook->api('/me/feed', 'POST', array(
                            'link' => 'https://www.facebook.com/myrepublica',
                            'message' => $message,
                             )
                           );
 }catch(FacebookApiException $e) {
  $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl( array(
                           'scope' => 'publish_stream',
                       )); 
  echo 'Please <a href="' . $login_url . '">login.</a>';
  error_log($e->getType());
  error_log($e->getMessage());
 }
}else{
 $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl( array( 'scope' => 'photo_upload') );
 echo 'Please <a href="' . $login_url . '">login.</a>';
}
?>
```

Hope this helps someone.